# how to hide result of find in android web view

Tags: android, webview

i am new with android and i try to create Epub reader.

i already read Epub Files in Android Webview and now i am taring create find functionality

i use this code for find any text in webview it works fine but wane i am go to next page
in my app stile my webview display find items .

code :

```
 int i = webViewRead.findAll(text);
 Method m = WebView.class.getMethod("setFindIsUp", Boolean.TYPE);
 m.invoke(webViewRead, true);
```

So, my problem is how to hide the result.
I already try to create new instants of my Webview( and Relode Webview Like webViewRead.reload(); ) but its not work for me.

is any anther way to do it.??
(my content witch i display in webview is xhtml pages).

And one More Thing with this method find text is highlighted with Green color
 is their any way to display find text in Red color.

Comment: ok my problem for hide result of find in next page is done, yes i just find with text witch never found ... it is not best solution but it works..   webViewRead.findAll("sysyassysyyssassysyysydsfsdsffsdfyyy12s44s51s25ddddtshbfjsbhd132565dfkjnldf5434dsfkln");

Answer (score 3):

Why not use:

```
webViewRead.clearMatches();
```

?

Greg